# how to get lat/long from selected result

Tags: api, maps, geocode

I have a search field that uses the google places api to autosuggest locations like so:

```
<input type="text" id="addressInput" name="addressInput" class="span3 search-query" placeholder="Enter location..">

<script>
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#addressInput")[0], {});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
console.log(place.address_components);
});
</script>
```

As the user types an addrress or city, it suggests just fine.  but once a user clicks on a result, how do I retrieve the lat and long of that selected option from the user?

The google examples seem to be find them based on dropping a marker.  I'm not displaying anything on a map at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following:

http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#ReverseGeocoding

It contains loads of information - you will find anything you need!

Comment: i've seen that, i just don't know how you get it geocode what ever address the user ends up inputting or selecting from the autocomplete results

Comment: Have you looked at the "geometry" object? i.e. console.log(place.geometry); According to the documentation, the location part of it contains the Long and Lat.

Answer (score 0):

The following should answer your question:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#getting_place_information